# How to use django-filter in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, get, django-filter

Here u can see my views with filter

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    min_price = django_filters.NumberFilter(name="price", lookup_type='gte')
    max_price = django_filters.NumberFilter(name="price", lookup_type='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = Ad
        fields = ['min_price', 'max_price']


class FindByTag(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Ad.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AdDetailSerializer
    filter_class = ProductFilter
```

Look down below for my urls for this view class

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/tag/select?', FindByTag.as_view())
]
```

And finally my serializer

```
class AdDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ad
        fields = '__all__'
```

So, the main problem is that i send a GET request to

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/tag/select?max_price=10000
```

and receive all records from my postgres db, filter doesn't work, can someone explain me why? Fell free to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Integration with Django Rest Framework is provided through a
> DRF-specific `FilterSet` and a **filter backend**. These may be found in the
> rest_framework sub-package

You need to specify the `filter_backend` provided by `django-filters` if you would like to directly use the `filterset` for filtering

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

class FindByTag(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Ad.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AdDetailSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = ProductFilter
```

#### EDIT

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    min_price = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name="price", lookup_expr='gte')
    max_price = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name="price", lookup_expr='lte')
```

Comment: it's seems to be answer, but what can you say about my url_pattern. I pasted your solution and the get an error TypeError at /api/v1/tag/select
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Comment: @NazarLike edited, some modifications on `ProductFilter`